# Android Studio 3.0 new project Issue

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I was working On an old project since last night, then I've started a new project and everything just got messy, for example, I can't make Package inside of my com.yoururl.appname, when I create one it won't add the folder instead my package name will rename like this for example "com.yoururl.appname.activity"

[image]

besides that, I can't make a class extending AppCompatActivity Gradle is fine and I've checked so many ways that were here in stack but none of them works, also I cant import gson library for dependency from project structure either when I'm searching for it nothing appears.

[image]

if you have the same issue or had and fixed it please help me too.

thanks

Comment: I have never seen such kind of error before! You must be careful and if persists report a bug!

Comment: yes it's a bug, and I've reported it, added some other dependency like cardview and design, then changed the version SDK to 27 also the appcompat and now it works, but gson still won't import with project structure, have to import it manually @Xenolion

Comment: Okay all the best **Happy Coding!** @Arash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was from new Gradle Update (4.0) , so I changed it back to 3.3 and it works just fine, added some other dependency like cardview and design, then changed the version SDK to 27 also the appcompat and now it works, but gson still won't import with project structure, have to import it manually